# The tag helper 'form' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

On a Razor Page I have:

```
<form @{ if (Model.Topic is not null) { <text>x-init="data.topic=@Model.Topic"</text> } } method="post">
```

I want to render `x-init="data.topic=@Model.Topic"` only if `Model.Topic` has a value.

I am getting the following error:

```
The tag helper 'form' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.
```

I tried a few options but I always end up with a compilation error like a quotes problem.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Razor has special-case handling for HTML element attributes that are rendered using the Razor syntax `<elementName attribute-name="@( value )">` (or just `<elementName attribute-name="@value">`): when `value` is `null` then Razor will omit the attribute name and value entirely.

So this should work:

```
@{
    String? xInitAttribValue = null;
    if( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this.Model?.Topic ) )
    {
        xInitAttribValue = "data.topic=" + this.Model.Topic;
    }
}

<!-- etc -->

<form x-init="@xInitAttribValue">

</form>
```

---

- When `this.Model.Topic` is `null`/empty/whitespace then Razor will render just `<form>`.
- When `this.Model.Topic` is *not* `null`/empty/whitespace (e.g. "`123abc`") then Razor will render something like `<form x-init="data.topic=123abc">`.

---

It can be inlined too:

```
<form x-init="@( this.Model.Topic is not null ? ( "data.topic=" + this.Model.Topic ) : null )">
```

or use an interpolated string: (I'm not a fan of interpolated strings because they default to `CurrentCulture` and make it hard to use `InvariantCulture`, *grumble*)

```
<form x-init="@( this.Model.Topic is not null ? ( $"data.topic={this.Model.Topic}" : null)">
```

Comment: And is there a solution to make it inline instead of declaring a variable? For example, I tried `x-init='@(Model.Topic is not null ? "data.topic=@Model.Topic" : null)'`...It almost works but `@Model.Topic` is not replaced by its value. It just shows `Model.Topic`

Comment: @MiguelMoura Use parentheses: `<form x-init="@(Model.Topic is not null ? ( "data.topic=" + this.Model.Topic ) : null)'>` or an interpolated string: `<form x-init="@(Model.Topic is not null ? ( $"data.topic={this.Model.Topic}" : null)'>`